# Changing NLog Variables (C#)

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, nlog

I would like to know how to check the value of the deviceId variable in the NLog.config file. Now, the deviceId variable in C# code and the deviceId variable in the NLog.config file are two different entities, but they should be the same variable.

С# code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        // log only Message 2
        //int res;
        //res = Sum(2, 5);
        //log.Debug($"{res}");

        int deviceId;
        deviceId = 1;
        //log.Debug("Message " + $"{deviceId}");
        log.Debug("");
        deviceId = 2;
        //log.Debug("Message " + $"{deviceId}");
        log.Debug("");
        deviceId = 3;
        //log.Debug("Message " + $"{deviceId}");
        log.Debug("");
    }
```

NLog.config code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>
  
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="file" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log" />
  </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
        <filters>
            <when condition="'${deviceId}' == '2'" action="Log" />
        </filters>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: You are talking about the variable `deviceId`, but your NLog configuration file only defines the variable `myvar`. Please [edit] your question to clarify this situation.

Comment: `"Message " + $"{deviceId}"` looks like the worst way to use string interpolation...

Answer (score 0):

How about in code:

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["deviceid"] = deviceid
```

and in the configuration

```
<when condition="equals(${deviceId}, '2')" action="Log" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [structured logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging) to provide a LogEvent property like this:

```cs
int deviceId = 2;
log.Debug("Message {deviceId}", deviceId);
```

Then you can output the [Event-Property](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer) value like this:

```
<when condition="'${event-properties:item=deviceId}' == '2'" action="Log" />
```

If the property value remains stable through the application-session, then you could also consider using [NLog GDC](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer) (Instead of having to include it with every LogEvent). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context

Notice [NLog Config Variables](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer) are a special animal in the world of NLog, that is used inside the `NLog.config`-file and allows you to declare a variable, and reference the variable-value throughout the `NLog.config`-file.